# MySql query syntax error c#

Tags: mysql

```
"INSERT IGNORE INTO DataBase.Table
(OrderNumber, CCHolder, CCPartial, CCEci, CCTransDate, 
CCPmtRef,CCStatus,CCMaster) " +
"VALUES (@orderNumber, @CCholder, 
@CCpartial, @CCeci, @CCtransDate, @CCpmtRef, @CCstatus, 
@CCmaster) " +
"WHERE @CCmaster NOT EXISTS (SELECT CCMaster FROM 
DataBase.Table)";
```

I need every time i insert new data CCMaster stays unique, tried various ways IF, NOT LIKE but nothing works.

Comment: Please show us the entire method. Also, be clear about what the code is doing and how that differs from what you **want** it to do.

Comment: I need to enter data from excell worksheet into DB, when i remove WHERE clause everything works fine, but i need to find a way to check not to duplicate CCMaster value in DB.

Comment: A unique constraint?

Comment: Yes CCMaster has unique index, but i'm trying to check if it is unique in query and than move it to Database. Can i do it without checking it in query?

Answer (score 2):

There's not enough context here. This doesn't look like a good solution for you, but have you tried something like

`WHERE @CCmaster not in (SELECT CCmaster FROM DATABASE.Table)`

Comment: I tried with not in, and it does not work. I need to enter data from excell worksheet into DB, when i remove WHERE clause everything works fine, but i need to find a way to check not to duplicate CCMaster value in DB.

Comment: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE 10386744 NOT IN (SELECT CCMaster FROM DataBase.Table)' at line 1" string

Answer (score 1):

Problem is the `WHERE` part in your `INSERT` statement which is wrong `"WHERE @CCmaster NOT EXISTS ...`. Either you use `INSERT INTO .. VALUES` construct or use `INSERT INTO .. SELECT FROM .. WHERE` construct but can't mix them both. `WHERE` clause isn't application if you are using `INSERT INTO .. VALUES` construct. You probably want to change your query like

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO DataBase.Table
(OrderNumber, CCHolder, CCPartial, CCEci, CCTransDate, 
CCPmtRef,CCStatus,CCMaster) 
SELECT @orderNumber, @CCholder, 
@CCpartial, @CCeci, @CCtransDate, @CCpmtRef, @CCstatus, 
@CCmaster FROM DataBase.Table
WHERE @CCmaster <> CCMaster
```

Comment: When i remove WHERE clause everything works fine, but i'm using data from excel worksheet to populate Table. So this way with select will not work for me, because i don't have a table to fetch parameters from.